# What is the word/phrase for what the end user of a computer sees and interacts with?

Tags: expressions, terminology, technical, computing

If you were to divide everything that makes up a computer and its software into what the average user interacts with, and everything else that works "behind the scenes", what would the "user-part" be called? What would the "behind the scenes" part be called?

For example, on my Windows laptop I'd consider things like the desktop, taskbar, and File Explorer "user-parts" and things like the command prompt or the BIOS as "behind the scenes". On a website, the HTML code would be "behind the scenes" and the visuals, text, etc. that the code produces would be the "user-part".

Comment: Are you talking about the interface and the code?

Comment: If you don't consider the terminal or BIOS interfaces to be "user interfaces", you might be looking specifically for "graphical user interface"

Comment: The command prompt is just as much a part of the user interface as the desktop and taskbar; in fact, its entire purpose is to "prompt" the user to enter "commands". Are you excluding it simply because many people don't use it often? (Some people use it quite often.)

Answer (score 4):

It is the **user interface**. Lexico has

> [user interface](https://www.lexico.com/definition/user_interface)
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> *Computing* The means by which the user and a computer system interact, in particular the use of input devices and software.

Behind the scenes are the

> [hardware](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hardware)
> The machines, wiring, and other physical components of a computer or other electronic system.

and the

> [software](https://www.lexico.com/definition/software)
> The programs and other operating information used by a computer.

Comment: The abbreviation UI is very common.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly: in 1970s military electronics the interface between man and machine was known as the Man-Machine Interface or MMI. At that time the use of *man* in that context didn't seem to cause a problem to the female engineers I worked with, though I can see that it might now be preferable to re-word it.

Comment: For what it's worth, "Man-machine interaction" now tends to be referred to as "Human-computer interaction" (HCI), presumably for the reason you mention :)

Comment: For a while it was also called "computer-human interaction"/CHI but I think they wanted to emphasise that the human was the important part when designing an interface, hence HCI.